# Ошибка UNIQUE constraint failed: user.user_id (SQLite)

Tags: python, база-данных, sqlite, aiogram

Пишу бота для телеграма. В процесе дошёл до создания БД. Использую БД (SQLite). Это мой первый опыт работы с БД

Ситуация следующая. Когда пользователь пишет сообщение, бот проверяет есть ли пользователь в БД и если его там нет - вносит его туда. Реализовал следующим образом:

```
@dp.message_handler()
async def mess_handler(message: types.Message):
    if not db.user_exists(message.from_user.id):
        db.add_user(message.from_user.id)
```

При первой попытке всё сработало, все аккаунты с которых я тестил бота попали в БД. Консоль никаких ошибок не выдавала. Сегодня начал с проверки совершенно другой функции бота. В код изменений не вносил, но консоль начала выдавать ошибку "UNIQUE constraint failed: user.user_id" и бот отказываеться работать. Участок кода, при исполнении которого выдаёт ошибку:

```
def add_user(self, user_id):
with self.connection:
    return self.connection.execute("INSERT INTO 'user' ('user_id') VALUES (?)", (user_id,))
```

Как это можно исправить?

Comment: Я понимаю, суть ошибки - бот пытается внести id пользователя в таблицу, но так как в БД это поле должно быть уникально, бот ловит тригер, ведь внести дважды один и тот же id невозможно. Только вот всё никак не получаеться научить бота сначала проверить есть ли уже этот id в таблице или нет

Comment: Достаточно просто -- достаточно проверить: ```SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM user WHERE user_id=ВАШ_АЙДИ) AS user_id_alias; ```, затем достать результат ```cursor.getInt("user_id_alias")``` и сравнить. 1 - есть, 0 - нет

Comment: Спасибо, сработало)

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать исключение через try и `except`:

```
def add_user(self, user_id):
with self.connection:
    try:
     self.connection.execute("INSERT INTO 'user' ('user_id') VALUES (?)", (user_id,))
    except:
        pass
```